# Screen protection for the iPad 3

Tags: screen, ipad

Is it true a screen guard reduces the clarity of an iPad 3 retina display? I dont want to risk scratching such an expensive investment. Any recommendations on screen protectors which satisfy the following criteria?

1. Fingerprint resistant
2. Retains the clarity of the retina display
3. Anti-glare
4. Does not interfere with the screen sensitivity
5. Does not interfere with swiping (you know.. that resistance you get when you
   swipe on plastic)

I had a matte protector on and it did points 1,3,4 and 5 really well. But I guess that's a given with matte screens. But it scattered the light too much that I took it off. Need recommendations on clear screens which meet all the above criteria.

Answer (score 1):

There are several companies which offers you all 5 points.

I've got a lot of experience with the Zagg [Invisible Shields](http://www.zagg.com/invisibleshield/apple-ipad-3-cases-screen-protectors-covers-skins-shields.php). They offer great quality and lifetime guarantee. But they are a bit expensive though. Quality comes at his price.

[image]

Then there is [BodyGuardz](http://www.bodyguardz.com/apple-ipad-2-cases-screen-protectors-covers-shields-skins-films.html?dir=asc&order=sort_priority). A bit cheaper, lifetime replacements as well but I don't have any experience with it. And they don't seems to offer a specific protector for the new iPad, but the protector of the iPad 2 will fit.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Michiel. Do you have personal experience with the Zagg screen for the iPad 3?

Comment: Since I don't have the new iPad, no. But I do have experience with the invisible Shield for iPhone 3G, iPhone 3GS, iPhone 4, iPhone 4S, iPad 1 and iPad 2. They all look the same and work exactly the same. It's a pain in the ass to get them attached though. So, you should be careful with that! But they offer excellent protections!

Comment: I have experience with the Zagg screen for iPad 3. It was excellent (although they're difficult to apply). It can take up to a week for it to become totally flat, and smooth out air bubbles, but once it does, it's invisible to the naked eye. Note: Make sure you buy the "HD" version!!! (This is completely invisible to the eye.)

Comment: One word of warning regarding the Zagg covers; if you have a case that covers the screen, they can absorb the ink from the cover. A real pain, and nothing you can do about it. It's due to the porous material they use to protect your screen. I had to send mine back for a full refund. Shame!

Answer (score 0):

Personally I really like the matte protectors, but I had to accept that they *do* scatter light more, and visibly alter the clarity of the screen.  That being said, I recently decided to try a "new material" that a friend told me about, and I have to say it's hands down the best non-matte screen protector I've ever tried (out of maybe a half dozen different varieties).

You can find it on Amazon:  [http://www.amazon.com/iSmooth-iPad-Screen-Protector-Replacement/dp/B00989QKA8/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00989QKA8)

I'm not really sure what it is that's different, but somehow the material is a huge cut above the other (admittedly, cheaper) screen protectors I've tried.  Once it's on, it truly is invisible and the overall quality is way higher.  I wouldn't likely have spent this much on a screen protector (which I realize is a pretty lame reality... $600 device and I want to spend less than $5 to protect the screen??  How backwards is that??) but since a friend recommended it, I'm glad I did.  These really are, in my opinion, the best out there.  The price also appears to have dropped a bit since I bought mine, and considering the above is a 3-pack... they're about the same price as the inferior ones I've bought before.

They are not matte however, and I've written to the company requesting that they make a matte version.  If they could somehow make a matte one out of this same material, I think I'd have my 100% perfect solution, rather than the 95% perfect I have with their clear version.

Hope that helps!